# React Firebase map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this problem that I am trying to fetch some reports using Firebase and React.

```
class Reports extends Component {
 state = {
  reports: []
 }

componentDidMount(){
const myUserId = fire.auth().currentUser.uid;

console.log(myUserId);

let reports = fire.database().ref('clients/' + myUserId + '/Reports/');

reports.on('value', function(snapshot){
  let reportsSnapshot = snapshot.val();
  this.setState({ reports: reportsSnapshot });
  console.log(this.state.reports);
}.bind(this));
}

render(){
  const reports = this.state.reports.map(report => {
    return <Report content={report.content} />
  });
  return (
    <div>
    {reports}
    </div>
  );
```

When I'm trying to compile this appears:

> TypeError: this.state.reports.map is not a function

How to properly fetch it and map? Is it a problem with setting the state properly?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: That error usually means you're calling `.map()` on something that isn't an array. I don't know firebase, but `snapshot.val()` is probably not an array but an object or something else. Also, you're trying to `console.log` the state directly after calling  `setState()`. That won't work properly, because `setState()` is asynchronous, so the state change won't reflect if you log on the next line.

Comment: Jayce has identified the most likely cause. If you're having trouble translating this into code, edit your question to include a snippet of the JSON at `clients/' + myUserId + '/Reports/` (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).